# Selenium - No Free Slots - After prolonged tests

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am using Selenium and things are good for a short suite run ( say 3 hrs run )

Once the test suite exceeds 3 hrs and run for say 5 hrs or 7 hrs, I am getting a No free slots available message from the Selenium grid.

See this image below

[image]

I am pretty sure, I am closing the driver references.

```
 driver.Close();
 driver.Quit();
 driver.Dispose();
```

This is what I get below.

[image]

These are all empty browsers. The browsers get launched, but does not fire a URL but launches the another browser and this keeps repeating. 
But I am sure I am disposing the driver object safely and no sessions are left behind ( using C# - driver.quit and driver.dispose

below is the code to launch Selenium Driver

```
var capabilities = BuildDesiredCapabilities();
        webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(gridHubURL), capabilities,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ApplicationConfiguration.RemoteDriverTimeOutValue));            
        webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ApplicationConfiguration.TimeOutValue));
        webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ApplicationConfiguration.TimeOutValue));
        return webDriver;
```

Am I doing something wrong.? Please let me know and thanks a lot for your help.

**EDIT1:**

The log which I get in the test results is

Initialization method OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session timed out after 120 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.

Comment: Timothy, I still didn't understand the problem here. No free slots is basically selenium's way of telling you that all the browser instances associated with all the nodes are currently in use and so a new test cannot be serviced. So you would need to find out why do your tests run long.
W.r.t to two browsers opening up for each of your test, its mostly due to your test code creating two webdriver instances per test. have you skimmed through your code to find out whether webdriver creation is happening anywhere else apart from the code section you shared ?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - Thanks a lot for your comments. What I presume is after 5 -7 hours, if I try to access the website, there is no response from the server. If thats the case, what I need to do to free the session. The above code creates a webdriver instance and try navigate to the URL. But the page keeps loading ( I presume ) . So I need to free the session if this happens. I will keep you/ the forum posted. Thanks again for your help. Much appreciated.